# Parsing the value of an input in angular breaks when using angular 1.3.x

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using angular 1.3.x, I have a parser in a directive assigned to an input.

When the user enters text into the directive the function that has been pushed to the $parses array is run. However when `ngModel.$setViewValue(res);` is called the same parse function is immediately called which didn't happen in angular 1.2.x

```
ngModel.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
    var originalVal = element.val();

    // do some logic to originalVal and set it as new ViewValue if changed

    if (originalVal != inputValue ) {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(res);
        ngModel.$render();
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Blackhole basically as the user types a thousand seperator number commas will be added to the text

Comment: Isn't that the use case for a $formatter instead of a $parser?

Comment: @JoseM I saw it done with $parser here: http://jsfiddle.net/dubilla/dj6mX/798/ but doesn't work with angular 1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $parsers documentation states

> Array of functions to execute, as a pipeline, whenever the control
>   reads value from the DOM. Each function is called, in turn, **passing
>   the value through to the next**. The last return value is used to
>   populate the model. Used to sanitize / convert the value as well as
>   validation. For validation, the parsers should update the validity
>   state using $setValidity(), and return undefined for invalid values.

The emphasis is mine.  So you need to return a value.

```
ngModel.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
    var originalVal = element.val();

    // do some logic to originalVal and set it as new ViewValue if changed

    if (originalVal != inputValue ) {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(res);
        ngModel.$render();
    }

    // make sure to return the updated view value
    return res;
});
```

I updated the sample fiddle to show that it works http://jsfiddle.net/dj6mX/1138/

Comment: thanks man! I am getting tired of angular and moving to ember and polymer